# Is it possible to turn off grid in orthographic view?

Tags: 3d-view, customization

Is it possible to turn of only the grid in orthographic 3D Views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have 'Grid Floor' turned off as moonboots shows, there's a quick trick .. when in one of the standard Orthographic Views, tap <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> on your Numpad..(rotating your view by + and - 15 degrees). This converts your standard Orthographic View to a User Orthographic View, from exactly the same angle, and the ortho background grid disappears

Answer (score 4):

Usually you open up the properties panel <kbd>N</kbd> and deactivate *Grid Floor* under [*Display*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html#display-panel). However, toggling that property is not supported for orthographic views. Your best bet is the activation of *Only Render* within the same panel, which basically hides all overlays and visualisations, see the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html#display-panel).

[image]

Comment: I don't think this works for orthographic views like top or front like the user asked, I don't think that is even supported

Comment: oh ok sorry but he didn't precise it